# Как получить значение с объекта и сравнить его

Tags: javascript, jquery

на странице имеется список input[type=radio], всего их 10 штук у каждого три варианта ответа.
Как с помощью js или jquery получить значение каждого из инпутов и сравнить его из заданным.
Сейчас получаю массив

```
var data = $('form').serializeArray();
```

Мне нужно через имя инпута получить значение, которое вернул метод и сравнить с мне нужным.
К, примеру

```
if ($('input[name='quest1]') === 'a') {
   curr += 1;
  }
  if ($('input[name='quest4]') === 'б') {
   curr += 1;
  }
```

Недавно начал изучать js, не могу дойти, как это сделать правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как минимум неверно идентификация элемента

Вот так надо

```js
//Что бы захватить элемент надо написать так

console.log($('input[name="quest1"]'));

//далее что бы его проверить на наличие какого либо значения, если это `input`

if ($('input[name="quest1"]').val == 'значение') {}

//А о каком value идет речь у  input type="radio" не имею малейшего представления
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quest1" value="rrr" type="radio" />
```

Comment: Речь о радио-кнопках. Подозреваю, что нужно `$('input[name="quest1"]:checked').val()`.